# How to include folder name in vue router path

Tags: javascript, apache, vue.js

I'm deploying the dist folder of my vue project to an apache server. I'm able to access the app, though the url looks like this: "ip-address/app" which presents a problem when the page is reloaded. I need to have the folder location of the app included in the url to avoid said issue: "ip-address/foldername/app" Do I need to configure this in vue-router or on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the `mod_rewrite` module on Apache.

One simple way is to create an `.htaccess` file in the folder you deployed, with the following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

That example file comes straight from [`vue-router` official docs page](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html).